# How to add action on enter in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

im new in angular and i need help. I need to add action on the enter button on the keyboard... So when user enter something in input fields and decide to click enter instead of using mouse must have the same results... What means that this function must be called with clicking enter... Is this enough code for u guys so you can gave me some answears?
Thanks :)

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      #filterName
      placeholder="Name"
      type="text"
      name="locationName"
      id="locationName"
    />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      #filterStationType
      placeholder="Type"
      type="text"
      name="stationType"
      id="stationType"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) use import import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
2) use decorator @HostListener:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  public KeyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      this.doSomething();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **component**'s class definition, you can add

```
@HostListener("window:keyup.enter") onKeyUp() {
        // do something here
}
```

This adds an event listener to this component that fires and executes whenever the enter key is released. Fill the body of this with what you want to happen on this event.